The response data variable populated by an AJAX call contains source code rather than the data sent from the server (on MS Edge)
I have the strangest issue! This only happens on MS Edge and only for certain users at a certain client. In summary when an ajax call is made to the server, instead of the response data variable holding the server response it is holding some source code from the platform instead. Code below...I'm not sure how this could be possible ?!? We cannot reproduce ourselves - but we can screen share with the user and confirm the issue
Ajax code:
        console.log("Calling: " + api);
        $.ajax({
            url: api,
            cache: true,
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                displayExceptionNotification("Error on call to " + api + ": " + errorThrown);
            }
        }).then(function (theData) {
// Use the server response
}

The variable 'theData' does not hold the JSON data coming back from the server instead it holds the contents of a totally unrelated .js file?!? We know this because we can remote view/share with the user, use the inspect/debug tool and hover over to see the value of 'theData' - see attached screenshot. I cannot come up with any reason why this would be - but of course when the follow on code runs instead of getting the expected JSON it's getting a bunch of raw js source code and failing..
Any ideas?


Do they use any proxy in Edge? If so, you can remove proxy and test again. Besides, what about clear browser cache and test again? Also, you can test in Edge InPrivate window to see if the issue still exists.

@YuZhou  You are right - viewing it in InPrivate does resolve the issue - I was not expecting that...good idea! Can you offer any reason how in the normal window a variable that should be populated from an AJAX call (which runs OK server side) could contain source code (the complete contents of a js file not even mentioned in the page making the AJAX call) but this does not  happen inPrivate.... I am so puzzled!!! Thanks for your help....

Glad it works in InPrivate mode! The difference between InPrivate mode and normal mode is InPrivate mode doesn't save any cache and cookies. So, I think the source code is from browser cache. But have no idea how it goes into response data. I'll post it as an answer so that it can help others in future with the same issue.

You can clear browser cache or test in Edge InPrivate window to see if the issue still exists.
The difference between InPrivate mode and normal mode is InPrivate mode doesn't save any browser cache and cookies. So, I think the source code is from browser cache. But have no idea how it goes into response data.
Ref link: Private browsing: What is it and how to use it
